# Find if an element of $(\mathbb{F}_{2^w})^l$ is invertible

Tags: abstract-algebra

Give an element $a(x) \in (\mathbb{F}_{2^w})^l$ (that I think is a *vector space*) modulo $l(x)=x^4+1$ with a *ring* structure because $l(x)$ is reducible, I like to know if this element is invertible and, if it is, who is its inverse.

For a polynomial notation and the modulo, the *vector space* $(\mathbb{F}_{2^w})^l$ can be defined as $\frac{\mathbb{F}_{2^w}[x]}{l(x)}$ and the *extension field* $\mathbb{F}_{2^w}$ as $\frac{\mathbb{F}_{2}[z]}{m(z)}$. And this $m(z)$ is irreducible to have this extension as a field.

I've tried with [sage](https://cloud.sagemath.com/):

```
_.<z> = GF(2)[]
K.<z> = GF(2^8, modulus=z^8+z^4+z^3+z+1)
R = PolynomialRing(K,'y'); X = R.gen()
x = R.quotient_ring(X^4 + 1,'x').gen()
a_x = (z+1)*x^3+x^2+x+(z)
~a_x

(z^3 + z + 1)*x^3 + (z^3 + z^2 + 1)*x^2 + (z^3 + 1)*x + z^3 + z^2 + z
```

And that is the result I expect, but I don't find the way to do it by myself.

I've tried with the [*Extended Euclidean Algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Pseudocode) to calculate the *greatest common divisor* as well as the inverse if they are coprimes without success. I suspect that I'm not applying correctly the algorithm because I use as $b$ the modulo and this element is congruent with $0$ when one works with it.

- Which is the correct way to address the problem? First know that an element is invertible, to then find this inverse.
- It is correct to call $\frac{\mathbb{F}_{2^w}[x]}{l(x)}$ as *vector space* modulo $l(x)$? As well as, $\frac{\mathbb{F}_{2}[z]}{m(z)}$ is a finite extension of the binary field?
- Is there an equivalence (that I don't know how to correctly call it) between $\frac{\mathbb{F}_{2^w}[x]}{l(x)}$ and $\frac{\mathbb{F}_{2}[z]}{l'(z)}$ with an $l'(z)$ degree $deg(m(z))\times deg(l(x))$ where $m(z)$ is the modulo for the binary extension $\mathbb{F}_{2^w}$?

Comment: Looking over the Question as a whole, your problem is apparently about finding which elements of a quotient of a polynomial ring over finite field $\mathbb{F}_{2^w}$ are invertible, where the quotient is taken with respect to a principal ideal generated by a *reducible* polynomial.  However there is room for improvement in your notation.

Comment: $a(x)$ is invertible if and only if it is coprime with $x^4+1$ on the field $\mathbb F_{2^w}$, so your approach is right.