# What's the correct naming and notation those algebraic structures?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm working to understand the maths behind the [Rijndael](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) cryptographic algorithm. Perhaps is too audacious to say that I understand how it works, because in fact, there are structures that I'm not sure even how they are called and what's they correct notation. I've recently ask another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1838350/find-if-an-element-of-mathbbf-2wl-is-invertible) and this has been pointed in the comments. I like to know how I can speak properly.

If I'm not wrong $\mathbb{F}_2$ is a field with $2$ elements (0 and 1). Two operations can be defined there, one like the addition being the *xor* and another like the product being the *and*.

It can be defined, above this binary field, an extension of some degree $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$. Operations in this field will become what we usually do in computation *bit-wise* operations.

The base field can define polynomials, denoted $\mathbb{F}_{2}[x]$, but one have to define it modulo one with degree $n$ to have an equivalent to the extension mention before. Noted as: $$ \frac{\mathbb{F}_{2}[x]}{n(x)}$$

When this polynomial $n(x)$ is irreducible, it satisfy the properties of a finite field; when $n(x)$ can be factorized, it satisfies the properties of a ring.

I've mention before the *Rijndael* algorithm. There is a point where it defines something above those previous. I think the notation is $(\mathbb{F}_{2^n})^l$. I'm not sure if in the previous paragraphs I've already mixed concepts, but here I'm almost sure I do.

*Rijndael* uses a polynomial *view* of this structure modulo a reducible polynomial: $$\frac{\mathbb{F}_{2^n}[y]}{l(y)}$$

Then perhaps this is a *quotient ring*. The first notation $(\mathbb{F}_{2^n})^l$ make me think this would be a *vector space* but I hope not, thinking for example in the product operation that is between two elements and not by an scalar.

Finally, how can I call this last "*meta*"-polynomial ring that has coefficients in the binary extension, without confusing it with the polynomials defined over the binary field.

Comment: Over a base field, every extension field can naturally be given the structure of a vector space (scalar multiplication is computed using the multiplication of the field).

Comment: Is this "_meta_"-polynomial a multivariate polynomial ring?