# Why the last steps in the Extended euclidean Greatest Common Divisor algorithm?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I've been trying to understand the [inversion in a polynomial ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1838350/) using the [extended euclidean gcd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1876209). In fact a polynomial ring with coefficients in an extension of the binary field. I would make notation and perhaps conceptual [mistakes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844635). I like to apologies when the case, and tell me the good way to learn it.

After many tries, I've ended inspecting the [sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) sources to understand what it does different than me. I've finally got it, but there is an step in the algorithm that I don't understand why is there. It is the last step and looks to be fundamental for succeed.

Taking the sage code as an example:

```
if b == zero:
    if a == zero:
        return (zero, zero, zero)
    c = ~leading_coefficient(a)
    d, u, v = c*a), c*x^0, zero
elif a == zero:
    c = ~leading_coefficient(b)
    d, u, v = c*b, zero, c*x^0
else:
    (u, d, v1, v3) = (one, a, zero, b)
    while v3 != zero:
        q = d // v3
        r = d % v3
        (u, d, v1, v3) = (v1, v3, u-v1*q, r)
    v = (d-(a*u) // b)
    if d != zero:
        c = ~leading_coefficient(d)
        d, u, v = c*d, c*u, c*v
return d, u, v
```

The algorithms I've read, like in the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Pseudocode) or in the [cohen's](https://books.google.es/books/about/A_Course_in_Computational_Algebraic_Numb.html?id=hXGr-9l1DXcC&source=kp_cover&redir_esc=y&hl=en) book, I can't see from where the last '*if*' comes from. Why to use the highest of the *gcd* candidate to multiply itself and the other [Bézout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) candidates?